# Problems with inheritance JAVA

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a class

```
public class Company {

    public  String b;// boss
    public String n;// name

    public Company(String boss, String name){
        b=boss;
        n=name;
    }

    public void print(){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, b +n);
    } 
}
```

And a class that extends it

```
public class MB extends Company {

    public static String b;// boss
    public static String n;// name
    private static String p;//product

    public MB(String boss,String name,String product){
        super(b,n); 
        p=product;
    }


     @Override
     public void print(){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,super.b +super.n +p);
     }
```

Class MB when I do print method I get null null and p value. Why is that? Shouldn't b and n be inherited from the class Company. I am new to JAVA so I might have missed something but reading previous questions and JAVA docs I couldn't find the answer. Personally I think the mistake is

```
public static String b;// boss
public static String n;// name
```

But cant figure out how to solve it.

Comment: Your guess is correct. You're shadowing `b` and `n`, not inheriting them. If you inherited them, there is no reason to redeclare the variables.

Comment: Looks like theres one brace missing

Comment: What @user3580294 is totally right. You create two static variables and didn't initialize then and you pass then to your super class `super(b,n)` which is giving you the null values

Comment: I started programming with c++ so public/private static is a bit unusual for me. What would be your suggestion, delete them in MB subclass?

Comment: Either initilize your static variables of MB class or change the call to super as `super(boss, name)` on the MB consructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
super(b,n);
```

you're passing `b` and `n` which refer to your `static` variables which have yet to be initialized and are therefore `null`. Perhaps you meant to pass `boss` and `name`.

Comment: still cant have to wait few minutes

Comment: @user3102621 Take note of the comments. Try not to have clashing names in your inheritance hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

in the inherited class Company, you must send super(boss,name) the received parameters and not the null strings defined in class MB